# How to trigger KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException when scanning new fingerprint

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44926774/3142611). I'm trying to trigger `KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException` when new finger print was added to the device but this exception was not triggering.

**MyCode**

*FingerprintActivity.java*

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec;
import android.security.keystore.KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException;
import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class FingerprintActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private KeyStore keyStore;
    // Variable used for storing the key in the Android Keystore container
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "androidHive";
    private Cipher cipher;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fingerprint);

        // Initializing both Android Keyguard Manager and Fingerprint Manager
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorText);

        // Check whether the device has a Fingerprint sensor.
        if(!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()){
            /**
             * An error message will be displayed if the device does not contain the fingerprint hardware.
             * However if you plan to implement a default authentication method,
             * you can redirect the user to a default authentication activity from here.
             * Example:
             * Intent intent = new Intent(this, DefaultAuthenticationActivity.class);
             * startActivity(intent);
             */
            textView.setText("Your Device does not have a Fingerprint Sensor");
        }else {
            // Checks whether fingerprint permission is set on manifest
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                textView.setText("Fingerprint authentication permission not enabled");
            }else{
                // Check whether at least one fingerprint is registered
                if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {
                    textView.setText("Register at least one fingerprint in Settings");
                }else{
                    // Checks whether lock screen security is enabled or not
                    if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {
                        textView.setText("Lock screen security not enabled in Settings");
                    }else{
                        generateKey();

                        if (cipherInit()) {
                            FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
                            FingerprintHandler helper = new FingerprintHandler(this);
                            helper.startAuth(fingerprintManager, cryptoObject);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    protected void generateKey() {
        try {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        KeyGenerator keyGenerator;
        try {
            keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get KeyGenerator instance", e);
        }

        try {
            keyStore.load(null);
            keyGenerator.init(new
                    KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(
                            KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                    .build());
            keyGenerator.generateKey();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
                InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
                | CertificateException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public boolean cipherInit() {
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/" + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/" + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
        }

        try {
            keyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return true;
        } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
            Log.e("newFingerPrintAdded", "newFingerPrintAdded");
            return false;
        } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
        }
    }
}
```

*FingerprintHandler.java*

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager;
import android.os.CancellationSignal;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.widget.TextView;

/*
 * Created by whit3hawks on 11/16/16.
 */
public class FingerprintHandler extends FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback {

    private Context context;

    // Constructor
    public FingerprintHandler(Context mContext) {
        context = mContext;
    }

    public void startAuth(FingerprintManager manager, FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject) {
        CancellationSignal cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        manager.authenticate(cryptoObject, cancellationSignal, 0, this, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationError(int errMsgId, CharSequence errString) {
        this.update("Fingerprint Authentication error\n" + errString);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpMsgId, CharSequence helpString) {
        this.update("Fingerprint Authentication help\n" + helpString);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
        this.update("Fingerprint Authentication failed.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
        ((Activity) context).finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void update(String e){
        TextView textView = (TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.errorText);
        textView.setText(e);
    }

}
```

What I've to change in my code to trigger `KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException` when new finger print was added to the device

Comment: It's not really clear how you're testing this, or on what device. If I create a key (the same kind of key as yours) on a Galaxy S7, then enroll another fingerprint, and then try initilizing a `Cipher` using my key, I get a `KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException`. But it looks to me like you're creating a new key everytime your `FingerprintActivity` is created, which doesn't make any sense. Normally you'd create the key once and keep using it until it gets invalidated, or the user chooses to delete it through some option in your app.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog/#readme

Go through the code and use compileSDKVersion +24

[image]